# SQL exclude certain records in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 8 tables: 
    received1, received2, received3, received4,
    recovery1, recovery2, recovery3, recovery4

Each of these tables has a field named "Item".

What I want to do is to find all the records that has a match between received and recovery, however, if an item is in received3 but not in recovery3, I don't want to show it.

Here's an example: An item is received, it goes into received1, then there's a recovery, it goes in recovery1. If it stops there, I want to select it.

Another exemple: An item is received, it goes into received1, then there's a recovery, it goes in recovery1, received again, goes into received2, recovery again, recovery2, then is received again, received3 but no recovery. I don't want to select this one because the item doesn't have a recovery.

EDIT: I'll be more clear, I want to get the items that their last received/recovery matches. If they have been received/recovered 2 times, I want to select it. However, if an item has been received 3 times and recovered 2 times, I don't want to select it(in this exemple, there will be an item in received1-2-3 and a recovery in 1-2 but not 3).

Comment: Just to be clear, is your only exception with Receive/Recovery 3, or for any element that is Received but not Recovered for the same numbered table?

Comment: also do you want to select the records in received and recovery 1 and 2 if 3 is missing or disclude them all?

Comment: can you also clarify the format you would want the result set in? Do you want a column representing each table or do you want only one column and an additional column to identify which table it is from? also can you add what column the relation is on i.e. is there a column named ItemID or something?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti solved it a few minutes ago. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it seems an 'item' always follows the receive-recover-receive-recover pattern. If that's the case, an item can only be considered if it appears a multiple of two times. Also since you have not given any further details on table structure I am assuming an 'item' does not repeat. In such case, the below query will give you the required.

```
SELECT Item FROM
(
(SELECT Item, Count(*) Cnt FROM 

(SELECT Item FROM Received1
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM Received2
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM Received3
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM Recovered1
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM Recovered2
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM Recovered3)A  GROUP BY Item)B
WHERE Cnt%2 = 0 --checks for multiples of 2
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I was looking for, i'm gonna try it.

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't work and I have no idea why, it doesn't find any records.

Comment: I removed the where condition and the first select so I can see the count, they are all at 1.

Comment: Try UNION ALL instead of UNION :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is left outer join the tables and in your where clause add the condition for excluding the records you don't want eg

```
SELECT  ...
FROM received1 left outer join received1 on (received1.item = received1) 
     left outer joing on received2 etc...
WHERE received1 != null OR received2 != null ...
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  received1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM  recovery1
             WHERE received1.time = received1.Item)
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM  received2
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM  recovery2
             WHERE received2.time = received2.Item)
UNION ALL 
.
.
.
.......
```